# Skin en ZIP para JW-Player no carga en Apache

Tags: html5, apache

Tengo un codigo, que sirve para poder insertar videos
utilizando el  reproductor JWplayer. (Flash + HTML5)
Sirve tanto para Flash, como para HTML5.

Si el navegador tiene instalado el pulgin de adobe flash player
y ademas soporta HTML5; La orden es que el video se reproduzca
utilizando flash, dejando a HTML5 como segunda opcion.

Si el navegador NO soporta HTML5, y si tiene instalado
el plugin de adobe flash player, el video se reproducira con flash.

Si el navegador soporta HTML5, pero no tiene instalado el plugin de
adobe flash player, el video se reproducira en HTML5.

Es un codigo integral que agrupa las etiquetas (Flash) y (HTML5)
en uno solo. Y de esta manera permitir que los videos se puedan reproducir
desde cualquier navegador.

El problema que tengo es que no he podido lograr que el skin glow.zip cargue
de manera adecuada en el reproductor.

La unica forma para que el skin glow.zip cargue en el reproductor, es teniendo habilitado, o instalado el plugin de adobe flash player. Y no deberia ser asi.

De tanto buscar encontre una pagina donde se hace exactamente lo que yo quiero, y funciona bien:
http://www.daoqigong.de/-test/12.html

el codigo es parecido al que yo utilizo; Decidi utilizar el mismo codigo de esa pagina, y ademas utilizar los mismos archivos de esa pagina (`glow.zip`, `jwplayer.swf`, `player.swf`). Pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema.

Creo que posiblemente debe ser un problema con mi servidor local apache.
Tal vez se deba ajustar, o añadir algo, para que el problema se resuelva.

Sera añadieno alguna linea al `.htaccess`?

o al archivo `httpd.conf`?

O que otra cosa podra ser?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>VIDEO FLASH+HTML5</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">Loading the player ...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("container").setup({
flashplayer: "player.swf",
file: "video.mp4",
autostart: true,
controlbar: "over",
volume: 100,
height: 338,
width: 600,
skin: "glow.zip"
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor publica tu codigo para poderte ayudar.

Comment: El codigo ha sido añadido en la pregunta formulada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Versión corta:** Descomprime `glow.zip` en la carpeta `skins`, sin ninguna carpeta adicional, con lo cual debes tener `skins/glow.xml`.

---

**Versión larga:**

Revisando el enlace citado, y tomando como `[base]` a la URL http://www.daoqigong.de/-test/skins se aprecia (en las herramientas del desarrollador, pestaña "Red") las siguientes peticiones:

- [base]/glow.xml
- [base]/controlbar/background.png
- [base]/controlbar/divider.png
- ...

Luego de ver el código del `.js` de JW-Player, éste reemplazará el `.zip` por `.xml`, así:

```
j.skin=j.skin.replace(/\.zip/i,".xml")
```

Con lo cual, el reproductor espera un archivo `.xml` que luego parsea, y comienza a cargar todos los recursos especificados en tal archivo.

Comment: Muchas Gracias..........funciono perfecto.....yo estaba haciendo el procedimiento al contrario.....Solo me queda una inquietud, al tratar de ver si  esas carpetas estan sueltas en el servidor de esa pagina, me aparece que no existen.  Por que razon ? y al ver por medio de desarrolador, a mi no me aparece las imagenes .png que mencionas arriba...Esa es mi ultima inquiteud, y nuevamente muchas gracias..

Comment: Es medida de protección para evitar listado de carpetas; si accedes directamente a un archivo se muestra sin problema. Para lo segundo, en Firefox hago F12, pestaña "Red", y "Recargar". Luego me lista los recursos pedidos.

Comment: ok. muchas gracias por tu gran colaboracion...Doy el tema como cerrado.

Comment: Pero no veo por ningun lado la opcion para dar como solucionado el tema.